# Display a message if posts dosen't exist on loop

Tags: php

I have a loop for bookmarked/favorite posts and for a fresh account if you don't have a bookmark post on bookmark page will show this message: 
Bummer, no bookmarks posts!

After the fresh account add 1 post to bookmark, the post appear on bookmark page, everything good.

But if the fresh account remove that only one bookmarked post from his bookmark posts then on page will show all posts from wordpress instead of this message : Bummer, no bookmarks posts!

What I need to set to display same message and not all posts from wordpress?

Here it's my loop:

```
<?php
                if(!is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="side-article">
                        <h2><?php _e('Please login if you want to see bookmarked posts!', 'Aruna');?></h2>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                else {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $bookmarks = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bookmarks', true);
        if($bookmarks) { 
        $bookmarks = unserialize($bookmarks);
        //Bookmarks                          
        $args = array();
        $args['post_type'] = 'post';
        $args['post__in'] = $bookmarks;
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 8;
        //performance improvements
        $args['no_found_rows'] = true;
        $args['update_post_term_cache'] = true;
        $args['update_post_meta_cache'] = true;

        $paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
        $args['paged'] = $paged;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();  
        get_template_part('includes/pagination');   
        endif;
        ?>
        <?php
        } else { ?>
        <div>
        <h2><?php _e("Bummer, no bookmarks posts!", 'Aruna');?></h2>
        </div>
       <?php }
       } ?>
```

Functions.php:

```
function teo_bookmark_submit() {
    // get the submitted parameters
    $postID = $_POST['post_id'];

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $bookmarks = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bookmarks', true);
    if(empty($bookmarks) ) {
        $bookmarks = array();
    }
    else {
        $bookmarks = unserialize($bookmarks);
    }
    if(!in_array($postID, $bookmarks) ) {
        $bookmarks[] = $postID;
    }
    $bookmarks = serialize($bookmarks);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bookmarks', $bookmarks);
    exit;
}

function teo_bookmark_remove() {
    // get the submitted parameters
    $postID = $_POST['post_id'];

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $bookmarks = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bookmarks', true);
    $bookmarks = unserialize($bookmarks);

    if(in_array($postID, $bookmarks) ) {
        $index = array_search($postID, $bookmarks);
        unset($bookmarks[$index]);
    }

    $bookmarks = serialize($bookmarks);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bookmarks', $bookmarks);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Since the key conditional depends on $bookmarks, it would be helpful to see how the user_meta is being updated to produce $bookmarks = false, and serialized.

Comment: Hey CK MacLeod, thanks for helping me. I updated the post

Comment: Haven't really helped you yet, but I'll say as a general comment before looking at things in detail that I suspect the problem may be in all of the serializing/unserializing.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so, first, you don't need to serialize/unserialize. `get_user_meta()` will return an array, and `delete_user_meta()` can remove a specific value.

So, simplifying a few other things here and below, your remove function would work like this (very simple):

```
function teo_bookmark_remove() {

    $postID = $_POST['post_id'];
    $current_user = get_current_user_id();

    delete_user_meta( $current_user, 'bookmarks', $postID );

}
```

Likewise bookmarks submit: Very simple (though probably here and in the previous function you should be using nonces or other security features- not sure about how rest of the set-up is handling the matter):

```
function teo_bookmark_submit() {

    // get the submitted parameters
    $postID = $_POST['post_id'];
    $current_user = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta( $current_user, 'bookmarks', $postID );

}
```

Now the display function:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {

    ?>
    <div class="side-article">
        <h2><?php _e('Please login if you want to see bookmarked posts!', 'Aruna');?></h2>
    </div>

    <?php } else {

    $current_user = get_current_user_id();
    $bookmarks = get_user_meta($current_user, 'bookmarks'); //returns array

    if ( ! empty($bookmarks) ) { 

            $args = array();
            $args['post_type'] = 'post';
            $args['post__in'] = $bookmarks; //post__in takes array
            $args['order'] = 'DESC';
            $args['posts_per_page'] = 8;
            //performance improvements
            $args['no_found_rows'] = true;
            $args['update_post_term_cache'] = true;
            $args['update_post_meta_cache'] = true;

    $paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $args['paged'] = $paged;

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; 

        wp_reset_postdata();  

        get_template_part('includes/pagination');   

    }

} else { ?>

    <div>
        <h2><?php _e("Bummer, no bookmarks posts!", 'Aruna');?></h2>
    </div>

   <?php }

}
```

Tested the "no bookmarks" part - the part that was giving you problems. Can't vouch completely for the results of the $bookmarks not empty alternative, of course, but works with a simple is_empty test.

Note: I believe on the above functions, the same value may end up appearing multiple times in the 'bookmarks' array. I don't think it's a problem for post__in or delete_post_meta (will delete all instances of particular value associated with the key), but may be if you use the 'bookmarks' array for other purposes. Not hard hard to fix that if you need to.

Comment: Hey CK MacLeod , again thanks for trying to help me but functions.php codes broke my bookmark script. I mean, when i bookmark a post it doesn't save bookmark page doesn't show nothing with that code, message no , bookmarks no because it doesn't save in user meta , I guess.. Basically without serialize and unserialize it doesn't save bookmarks posts

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly, and not in a position to debug the script... we'd also have to see the input code, I think, for starters. Standard procedure on the $_POST variables would be to start with an "isset," then go through a nonce, then do an `if ($_POST === ...)` etc. Probably should have noted in the simplified versions...

Comment: Key point, I think, is that serialize and unserialize shouldn't be necessary at any point. The functions already handle that.

Comment: With what you give me for functions.php doesn't work. I bookmark a post : http://imgur.com/zIPX4Th then F5 to refresh the page and the bookmark post doesn't save http://imgur.com/MyYUgTf . I don't think will work without serialize and unserialize and on bookmark page if I delete this : $bookmarks = unserialize($bookmarks); basically will broke my page http://imgur.com/3v7EDB8

Comment: I don't understand - when you say you're bookmarking the post, what function/input  submit the post ID as a $_POST variable?

Comment: Hey all functions for bookmark are there in that functions.php that I give you .You want to chat on something ?

Comment: ...the code underlying the stars you showed me might help.. My first assumption was that the variables were probably $_POST'ed by a form submitted in a template file...

Comment: nope .. the codes for bookmarks does not contains nothing about $_POST

Comment: Still don't understand where you're getting "codes for bookmarks" from... Nothing so far actually bookmarks a post leading to your "submit" function actually getting called

Comment: Do you wanna speak on skype ? I can show you on share screen everything you want.

Comment: Nyah.. not really... I've got to get to some things... would be easier if I could just see the code as described... to understand what a user is doing when he or she "bookmarks" a post.

Comment: Ok , I understand :) Here it's what I found all about bookmarks.             1: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6366   ||                                        2:  http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6367    ||                                     3:  http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6368   ||                                        4:  http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6369  ||

Comment: Ah - so it's an Ajax submit. Will check a possible simple fix (that doesn't address the serialization question) later.